# Is it possible to add padding to an anchor tag on line break?

Tags: html, css

I have the following link with a padding. On mobile screen, it has a line break. Would it be possible to add a padding on the end of the first and the start of the second line as well?

```css
div {
  max-width: 30rem;
  margin: 5rem auto;
}
a {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: red;
  line-height: 200%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#">Read More: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</a>
</div>
```

Comment: If that's the full HTML, give the link `display: block`.

Comment: @ceejayoz - Yes, that's an option, but it'd make the second line the same width as the first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`box-decoration-break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-decoration-break):

```css
div {
  max-width: 30rem;
  margin: 5rem auto;
}

a {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: red;
  line-height: 200%;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
          box-decoration-break: clone;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#">Read More: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</a>
</div>
```